# Invalid Operands to binary expression (NSNumber* __strong and NSNumber*)

Tags: objective-c, iphone

```
nsnumber *totaldur=0;

totalDur+=(NSNumber*)[dict valueForKey:@"tracktime"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't perform addition on NSnumber for this

```
NSNumber * totaldur =[NSNumber numberWithInteger:20];

totaldur = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:([number1 integerValue] + [[dict valueForKey:@"tracktime"] integerValue])];
```

**//// first of all convert both numbers to same data type like (nsinteger,int,float) and then apply addition on them and in the end save sum in nsnumber object**

Hope it helps

Comment: you are more than welcome